# Probability Mass Functions of X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains 5 balls numbered from 1 to 5. We draw 3 of them at random without replacement.

(a) Let X be the largest number drawn. What is the probability mass function of X?

(b) Let Y be the smallest number drawn. What is the probability mass function of Y ?

I know that the (probability) mass function of a discrete random variable X is a function f : R→ [0,1] given by f(x) = P(X = x), and i was wondering how i would use this to answer the question?

Comment: There are only $\binom 53=10$ ways to choose the numbers; just do it by hand.

Comment: Again a question with no personal input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A urn contains $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$. We draw $m$ of them at random without replacement. Let the largest ball number be $k$. The probability mass function of $k$ is given by

$$P_k={k-1\choose m-1}\Big/{n\choose m},\quad k\geq m.$$

This is because when the maximum is $k$, the other $m-1$ balls must all be chosen from the balls $1,2,\ldots,k-1$. You can varify

$$\sum_{k=m}^n{k-1\choose m-1}={m\choose m}+{m\choose m-1}+{m+1\choose m-1}+\cdots+{n-1\choose m-1}={n\choose m},$$

so the probability is normalized. Similarly, one can find the distribution of the smallest number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $X$ first find values $\mathsf P(X\leq x)$.

If you are ready with that then use: $$\mathsf P(X=x)=\mathsf P(X\leq x)-\mathsf P(X\leq x-1)$$

For $Y$ likewise but now with values $\mathsf P(Y\geq y)$.